# Wrap delegate in std::function?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, clr

I have a native, unmanaged C++ library that I want to wrap in a managed C++ class to provide clean and type safe way to access the unmanaged class from C# without having to do PInvoke.

One the methods I'm trying to wrap have the following signature:

```
void Unmanaged::login(
  const std::wstring& email,
  const std::wstring& password,
  std::function<void()> on_success,
  std::function<void(int, const std::wstring&)> on_error);
```

Trying to wrap this however turns out to be not easy at all. The obvious way:

```
public delegate void LoginSuccess();
public delegate void LoginFailed(int, String^);

void Wrapper::login(String ^ email, String ^ password, LoginSuccess ^ onSuccess, LoginFailed ^ onError)
{
    unmanaged->login(convert_to_unmanaged_string(email), convert_to_unmanaged_string(password), [onSuccess]() {onSuccess(); }, [](int code, const std::wstring& msg) {onError(code,convert_to_managed_string(msg))});
}
```

Fails because managed C++ doesn't allow (local) lambdas (in members).

I know I can use Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate to get a native pointer to the delegate, but I still need to provide a "middleware" to convert between managed/unmanaged types (such as std::wstring).

Is there perhaps a better way than using managed C++ altogether?

Comment: I have modified the question tags, as I believe this is C++/CLI, not Managed C++..

Comment: @RichardHodges: Not really helpful when the stated goal is making C++ code accessible from C#. We could argue all day about the merits of C# versus C++, but telling the asker to use C++ isn't really solving the problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges: But you still can't accomplish the goal in the very first line of the question. "I have a native, unmanaged C++ library that I want to wrap in a managed C++ class *to provide clean and type safe way to access the unmanaged class from C# without having to do PInvoke.*"

Comment: The managed c++ is just for wrapping, if creating a flat, C-style type interface that I PInvoke from C# is better then I can do that, however somewhere the .net <-> native translation needs to happen and I would assume that would be easier in managed C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because you can't capture a managed object in a native lambda. But you can easily wrap a managed object in an unmanaged one, with the help of the `gcroot` class:

You'll need these headers:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

And here's the wrapper code:

```
static void managedLogin(String^ email, String^ password, LoginSuccess^ onSuccess, LoginFailed^ onError)
{
    gcroot<LoginSuccess^> onSuccessWrapper(onSuccess);
    gcroot<LoginFailed^> onErrorWrapper(onError);

    Unmanaged::login(
        msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(email),
        msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(password),
        [onSuccessWrapper]() {
            onSuccessWrapper->Invoke();
        },
        [onErrorWrapper](int code, const std::wstring& message) {
            onErrorWrapper->Invoke(code, msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(message));
        }
    );
}

public ref class Wrapper
{
public:
    static void login(String ^ email, String ^ password, LoginSuccess ^ onSuccess, LoginFailed ^ onError)
    {
        managedLogin(email, password, onSuccess, onError);
    }
};
```

The [`gcroot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx) object wraps a [`System::Runtime::InteropServices::GCHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx), which will keep the managed object alive. It's an unmanaged class you can capture in a lambda. Once you know this, the rest is straightforward.

For some reason, the compiler complains if you try to use a lambda in a *member* function, but it's totally fine with a lambda in a free function. Go figure.

Comment: Wow, this is great! And just to make sure: The login operation is asynchronous, will the gcroot objects still be kept alive even though the Wrapper::login method returns immediately?

Comment: @monoceres yes, they do have a copy constructor which does the right thing, just make sure you capture them by value and not by reference.

Comment: Great! I haven't programmed in C++ in several years, so lambdas seems new and magical to me :-)

Comment: Spoke to soon, your code still gives: "a local lambda is not allowed in a member function of a managed class"

Comment: VS2015 as well, you can see my full class definition here: http://pastebin.com/9vCB0aiM

Comment: @monoceres stupid compiler, I don't know why it cares ;) see my edit for a workaround. I just used the [fundamental theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering).

Comment: Haha, that is weird. Kinda of annoying though as I may need to access private members and it won't accept a static member function (hmm, maybe you can make the static function a friend to the managed class?). Anyways, still perfectly acceptable so I'm re-accepting ;-)

Comment: @monoceres `friend` won't work with a managed class, but you can use the `internal` access modifier, which is equivalent to friending the whole assembly. Then, just add an argument of type `Wrapper^` to the static function :) You'll have to juggle with a couple forward-declarations though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best thing I could come up with quickly. I think you're gonna be stuck with wrappers to hand marshal your args back to managed types unless there is some whole auto callback marshaling thing I'm not aware of. Which is quite possible since I've only been doing managed programming for a week.

```
delegate void CBDelegate(String^ v);
typedef void(*CBType)(String^);
typedef std::function<void(const wchar_t*)> cb_type;

cb_type MakeCB(CBType f)
{
    gcroot<CBDelegate^> f_wrap(gcnew CBDelegate(f));
    auto cb = [f_wrap](const wchar_t *s) {
        f_wrap->Invoke(gcnew String(s));
    };
    return cb;
}

void f(cb_type);

void MyCallback(String^ s) {
    Console::WriteLine("MyCallback {0}", s);
}

void main() {
    f(MakeCB(MyCallback));
}

#pragma unmanaged

void f(cb_type cb)
{
    cb(L"Hello");
}
```

EDIT 1: Improved code.

EDIT 2: Steal good ideas from @Lucas Trzesniewski. Also CBWrap was not needed

EDIT 3: If you prefer to wrap the function instead of the callback.

```
delegate void CBDelegate(String^ v);
typedef void(*CBType)(String^);
typedef std::function<void(const wchar_t*)> cb_type;

void f(cb_type);

void f_wrap(CBType cb) {
    gcroot<CBDelegate^> cb_wrap(gcnew CBDelegate(cb));
    auto cb_lambda = [cb_wrap](const wchar_t *s) {
        cb_wrap->Invoke(gcnew String(s));
    };
    f(cb_lambda);
}

void MyCallback(String^ s) {
    Console::WriteLine("MyCallback {0}", s);
}

void main() {
    f_wrap(MyCallback);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I actually did something similar myself with lots of template trickery, the other answer seems to be a lot simplier though :)

Comment: Lucas's use of gcroot is very clean. See my adaptation above. Also my previous CBWrap function was extraneous. It can all go in the lambda. My approach giving you a way to pass a CBType to anything vs Lucas giving you a clean wrapper for a single unmanaged function.